# Valid Date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ext.net

After calling Ext.Date.parse in JavaScript function, how to check whether the parsed date is valid?

```
var d = Ext.Date.parse(value, "c");
```

Comment: There must be thousands of post about it, just google it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: What do you mean by **valid**? For instance: if you input `2004-02-30` you can get the date `2004-03-01` but does that mean it's valid?

Comment: @Halcyon d is always undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
dt = Ext.Date.parse("2006-02-29 03:20:01", "Y-m-d H:i:s", true); // returns null
```

Parameters

```
input : String

The raw date string.
format : String

The expected date string format.
strict : Boolean (optional)

true to validate date strings while parsing (i.e. prevents JavaScript Date "rollover"). Invalid date strings will return null when parsed.

Defaults to: false
```

[resource here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.Date)